# Reports using java collections

Tags: java, collections, report

I am trying to create a day wise report which should show tasks created by users everyday.

and it should be display like this

```
      01 jan   02 jan 03 jan ..... total

 user1   3        5     10           18
 user2   5        6      9           20
 .
 .
 .
 total   8        11     19          38


I have got my sql query written which returns me list of records


select count(fe.id) , u.username as username, Date(fe.created_at) as createdAt 
from tasks t inner join users u on t.user_id = u.id
group by createdAt,username
```

it returns me data like

```
    3   Mark    2012-10-01
    2   John    2012-10-02
    3   Sam     2012-10-02
    1   Gary    2012-10-03
    1   John    2012-10-03
    3   harry   2012-10-03
    4   Sam     2012-10-03
    1   John    2012-10-04
    7   Gary    2012-10-04
    4   Sam     2012-10-04
```

I am getting these records as List. So what is the best way to show them in a above report. Is this data sufficient to  display it in above report form and break the List into userwise or datewise. Or if there us any tool available to display this type of reports.

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: there are reporting utilities such as BIRT, but for your situation just printing them is probably enough, or maybe format as HTML.

Comment: I believe we're not the right audience for your question. As you ask for the requirement, like: How to display the reports? You should make up your mind and decide how you want to present them: show in console? Export to some file (pdf/html/...)? ....? Then we can help in a way how to solve it technically.

Comment: I am able to display in above format but the only thing is I am unable to display the column total. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382657/calculate-total-of-each-columns-in-jstl for more detail