# Calculate total of each columns in jstl

Tags: jsp, collections, html-table, jstl

I am having a report like this

```
         01 jan  02 jan  03 jan  ...  total

 user1   3       5       10           18
 user2   5       6       9            20
 .
 .
 .
 total   ?       ?       ?            38
```

I am able to calulate each row total at end using my JSTL code. I don't find the way to calculate columns total at end mark with '?'.

For row total I am using like

```
<c:forEach var="colNames" items="${listOfRecords}">
    <tr>
        <td>${colNames.key}</td>
        <c:set var="htotal" value="0" />
        <c:forEach var="noOfTasks" items="${colNames.value}" varStatus="status">
            <td>${noOfTasks.value}</td>
            <c:set var="htotal" value="${htotal+noOfTasks.value}" />
        </c:forEach>
        <td class="foo">${htotal}</td>
    </tr>
</c:foreach>
```

Here `${listOfRecords}` is `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "hashmap [String, [String, Integer]]"? Maybe this `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>` ?

Comment: yes its HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> as it was not displaying it if I put < symbol

Comment: I think your colNames is actually rowNames, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @BalusC thanks for modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all I've been able to come up with:

```
<jsp:useBean id="column_totals" class="java.util.LinkedHashMap" scope="page"/>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${listOfRecords}">
    <tr>
        <td>${row.key}</td>
        <c:set var="row_total" value="0"/>
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${row.value}">
            <td>${column.value}</td>
            <c:if test="${empty column_totals[column.key]}">
                <c:set target="${column_totals}" property="${column.key}" value="0"/>
            </c:if>
            <c:set target="${column_totals}" property="${column.key}" value="${column_totals[column.key] + column.value}"/>
            <c:set var="row_total" value="${row_total + column.value}" />
        </c:forEach>
        <td class="foo">${row_total}</td>
    </tr>
</c:foreach>
<tr>
  <td>total</td>
  <c:forEach var="column_total" items="${column_totals}">
     <td>${column_total.value}</td>
  </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

Had to change some names cause I couldn't understand with yours sorry.

I think it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use EL in `<c:set var>`. See also [tlddoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) ("requesttime" says `false`, thus no EL allowed). I'd use a `<jsp:useBean class="java.util.HashMap">` trick.

Comment: @BalusC You're right :/ Changed it for a Map, what do you think about it now?

Comment: Looks legit. But as you're iterating over map values directly in the totals instead of obtaining them by an ordered key set, you'd better make it a `LinkedHashMap` to maintain the insertion order.

Comment: @BalusC Yeah, I have the bad habit of using `HashMap` for everything :/

Comment: No worries. I suggested that myself in the 1st comment (although it was a bit meant as a generic hint). The OP is also talking about `HashMap` all the time, I wonder if he's well aware about its  unordered nature.

Comment: @BalusC I hadn't noticed that you alreay said to use a Map... o.O!

Comment: Yes Adrián, its working perfectly.Thanks a lot for your effort.